# How to regenerate an index for a sparse checkout with local changes?

Tags: git

I use git with sparse checkouts to work with subsets of a very large monolithic repository. The performance is good with sparse checkouts, terrible without.

On occasion my index gets corrupted (Xcode's git integration is my normal root cause, but I've managed it various different ways).

For a normal worktree, this is fine, I just delete the index file and `git reset`, I might have had some staged changes which drop back to unstaged, but generally I don't lose anything important.

But for a sparse checkout, `git reset` will not take the sparse manifest into account from a clean slate, and so will conclude that all files in the full repo that aren't in the worktree (ie, everything that my sparse checkout excluded) must have been deleted, leaving me with an enormous list of "deleted" files.

So the recommended way of resetting the index with sparse checkout information (ie, setting the skip-worktree flags), is to call `git read-tree -mu HEAD`, but this requires that there are no unstaged changes, I need to keep those unstaged changes, and can't commit them or stage them or anything, since I have no index (and given all the "deleted" files, it would also take a very long time to check them out just so git could delete them again once it realises they aren't in the sparse checkout).

If I were willing to lose my local changes, I could instead call `git read-tree -m --reset HEAD`, which works. But since the goal is keeping my uncommitted changes, that isn't really sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've found thus far is to move all my changes to a temporary location, run `git read-tree -mu HEAD`, then delete all the files git creates and replace them with the original changes.

This does mean waiting for git to recreate all the sparse checkout files, but at least I don't have to wait for it to create all the other files in the repo that I don't want to checkout (which tends to be *much* longer).